# Aligning Table in Latex 2

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

Could you please helping me to draw a nice big tables

like this one , I don't know how to mange the big table in LateX

[image]

Here is the table source code. Any help will be much appreciated. Regards

```
 \documentclass[13pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm,exscale,commath}
 \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

  \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
  \usepackage{xspace}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{wasysym}
  \usepackage{maybemath}
  \usepackage{type1cm}
  \usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.9cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{fancybox}


   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{bigstrut}

   \usepackage{makecell}
   \setcellgapes{4pt}

  \fancypage{
 \setlength{\fboxsep}{11pt} \doublebox}{} 

  \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|r|ccc|c|c|c|c|c|cc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}[6]{*}{\textbf{Thời \newline{} gian}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}[6]{*}{\textbf{Nội \newline{} dung}}} & \multicolumn{5}{p{10.435em}|}{\textbf{Hình thức\newline{} tổ chức dạy học}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}[6]{*}{\textbf{Yêu cầu\newline{} SV chuẩn bị\newline{}trước khi \newline{}đến lớp}}} \bigstrut\\
   \cline{5-9}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Giờ 
   lên 
  lớp} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{HĐ \newline{}theo 
   \newline{}nhóm}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Tự 
  \newline{}học}} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut\\
  \cline{5-7}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & LT    & BT/TH & TL    &       
   &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{9}[4]{*}{Tuần 1}} & \multicolumn{3} 
     {p{12.93em}|}{\textbf{Chương 1. Môđun-\newline{}Đồng cấu môđun}} & 
     \multirow{9}[4]{*}{3} & \multirow{9}[4]{*}{} & \multirow{9}[4]{*}{} & 
     \multirow{9}[4]{*}{} & \multirow{9}[4]{*}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} 
     {\multirow{9}[4]{*}{Đọc tài liệu\newline{}[1]-[2]-[5]}} \bigstrut[t]\\
       & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{1. Môđun}} &       &       &       &       
         &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{1.1. Định nghĩa và ví dụ} &       &       &       
       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{1.2. Môđun con} &       &       &       &       
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{1.3. Môđun thương} &       &       &       &       
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut[b]\\
    \cline{2-4}          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{2. Đồng cấu môđun}} &       
     &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut[t]\\
      & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{2.1. Các định nghĩa và ví dụ} &       &       &       
     &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
      & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{2.2. Một số tính chất} &       &       &       &       
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
      & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{2.3. Một số định lý về đồng cấu môđun} 
      &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
      \bigstrut[b]\\
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Tuần 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Bài tập} &       & 
       3     &       &       & 6     & \multicolumn{2}{p{6.07em}|}{Đọc tài 
       liệu \newline{}[1]-[2]-[5] và chuẩn bị BT\newline{}ở nhà\newline{}} 
       \bigstrut\\
       \hline
       \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{6}[4]{*}{Tuần 3}} & \multicolumn{3} 
      {p{12.93em}|}{\textbf{3. Tích trực tiếp-Tổng trực tiếp của các môđun}} 
       & \multirow{6}[4]{*}{3} & \multirow{6}[4]{*}{} & \multirow{6}[4]{*}{} 
      & \multirow{6}[4]{*}{} & \multirow{6}[4]{*}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} 
    {\multirow{6}[4]{*}{Đọc tài liệu\newline{}[1]-[2]-[5]}} \bigstrut[t]\\
       & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{3.1. Xây dựng tích trực tiếp của các 
   môđun} &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
      & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{3.2. Tính chất phổ dụng của tích trực tiếp} &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
      & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{3.3. Xây dựng tổng trực tiếp của các môđun} &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
      & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{3.4. Tính chất phổ dụng của tổng trực tiếp} &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut[b]\\
        \cline{2-4}          & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.93em}|}{\textbf{4. Tổng 
        trực tiếp trong- Hạng tử trực tiếp}} &       &       &       &       
      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut\\
   \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Tuần 4} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Bài tập} &       & 3     
   &       &       & 6     & \multicolumn{2}{p{6.07em}|}{Đọc tài liệu 
      \newline{}[1]-[2]-[5] và chuẩn bị BT\newline{}ở nhà\newline{}} 
    \bigstrut\\
         \hline
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{TỔNG:}} & \textbf{20} & \textbf{22} & 
       \textbf{3} &       & \textbf{90} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
         \end{tabular}%






           \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What precisely is your question? Do you want to make the table more narrow, such that it fits on the page?

Comment: @marmot Yes! I want to make the table more narrow, and it fits on the page

Answer (score 0):

The `longtable` package lets tables that don't fit in one page continue
on the following page. The package and its documentation are at:
https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable

Regarding making a table fit in the width of a page, a key point is
dealing with line breaks inside cells. The source code in the question
has `\newline` instructions in columns of type `c` or `r`,
but newlines can only work in columns of type `p` (in paragraph mode).